# JDBC for MySQL connection: works with MySQL Workbench, not with JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a database server running on a bluehost machine, and I am giving myself remote IP access (via my IP address).

On my client machine, I have MySQL Workbench, and I have some Java code. MySQL workbench is getting the connection, using the database that I would like it to. With the driver manager connection, I cannot specify my database, such as with a forward slash after the port # in the URL, or it will give a connect error.

I can get the connection with the same userid and password using Workbench or the driver manager, but with JDBC it doesn't want to give me access to the same database.

When I try to execute this `(JDBC): "use database"`, I get:

> Access denied for user 'userid'@'184.11.22.%' to database 'database'

The URL I am using is

```
jdbc:mysql://(server-ip):(port)
```

If I try to append a '/(database)' on to the URL it gives the access violation.  MySQL Workbench isn't getting any other special information, but appears to connect with the specified default schema.  Same client machine; same user id and password. What is going wrong with the JDBC connection?

Java code added:

```
    db = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://74.220.192.113/advanfc7_atm?" + 
        "user=(myuserid&password=(mypwd)");
    System.out.println("Connected.");
  statement = db.createStatement();
  statement.execute("use advanfc7_atm");
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("InitDB() "+e.getMessage());
```

}

I've also done it with 3 parameters to getConnection(), separating userid and password to the 2nd and 3rd params.

Comment: when you attempt to access the db using JDBC, are you specifying a username and password in any way?  Please show the java code you are using to try to connect to the db

Comment: I added a code snippet above.  I always specify userid and password, and I am using the same userid in both Workbench and in Java.

Comment: With both options, are you getting the `Access denied` message? If so, on MySQL Workbench (or MySQL CLI),  check the hosts that can be used by your user: `select distinct Host from mysql.user where User='myuserid'` (you'll need to use MySQL's `root` user to run this query)

Comment: I transposed two letters in the database name.  atm - amt.  amt works.  In response to your question, I do not have root access on this machine.  But I do now have database access.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small syntax error in your getConnection code:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://74.220.192.113/advanfc7_atm?" + 
        "user=(myuserid&password=(mypwd)");
```

Note that the closing parenthesis on `user=(myuserid` is missing.  It should be `user=(myuserid)`.

**Instead:**
Since each driver has different url syntax, it's generally safer to use the [`DriverManager.getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method instead.

**Example usage:**

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://74.220.192.113/advanfc7_atm", 
        "myuserid",
        "mypwd");
```

Comment: Sorry.  That is a syntax error in edited syntax.  I added parentheticals for usierid and password to put it here. I have also used both signatures; one arg or three.

Comment: Ok, so it was jut an issue with how you typed up the question.  Did you try to use the `getConnection(url, username, password)` method instead?

Comment: It turns out to also be how I typed up the database name.  I transposed two characters in it, which caused my problem.